# Azure KeyVault Secret Get Throws CredentialUnavailableException

Tags: azure, spring-boot, logback, azure-keyvault, azure-cli

I'm using AzureKeyVault to store secretes and retrieve them in my application. I'm using Spring Boot with the latest versions for azure-identity and azure-security-keyvault-secrets libraries. This is the code that does the job:

```
private SecretClient createDefaultAzureCredential() {
    DefaultAzureCredential defaultCredential = new DefaultAzureCredentialBuilder()
        .build();

    return new SecretClientBuilder()
        .vaultUrl(keyVaultUri)
        .credential(defaultCredential)
        .buildClient();
  }

  @Cacheable
  public String getSecret(String secretKey) {
    KeyVaultSecret secret = createDefaultAzureCredential().getSecret(secretKey);
    return secret.getValue();
  }
```

I'm authenticated using Azure CLI, and everything works fine. I can get my secrets.
Because `DefaultAzureCredential` is using the following order of trying to authenticate: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y80vq.png,
my logs are filled with exceptions of type:

```
com.azure.identity.CredentialUnavailableException: EnvironmentCredential authentication unavailable. Environment variables are not fully configured.
   at com.azure.identity.EnvironmentCredential.getToken(EnvironmentCredential.java:123)
   at com.azure.identity.ChainedTokenCredential.lambda$getToken$2(ChainedTokenCredential.java:55)
   at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFlatMap$FlatMapMain.onNext(FluxFlatMap.java:378)
   at reactor.core.publisher.FluxIterable$IterableSubscription.slowPath(FluxIterable.java:267)
---logs trimmed----
```

For logging, I'm using logback.

There is a way to remove logs caused by failing attempts to authenticate? I know that I can disable the logs for the class that throws them using logback, but I don't want to do that because I'm afraid that I can lose so essential logs that can be used when debugging.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are using a VM, pls validate that you are setting the following system [environment variables](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/tree/master/sdk/identity/Azure.Identity#environment-variables):

- `AZURE_CLIENT_ID` - service principal's app id
- `AZURE_TENANT_ID` - id of the principal's Azure Active Directory tenant
- `AZURE_CLIENT_SECRET` - one of the service principal's client secrets

And for below question:

> There is a way to remove logs caused by failing attempts to
> authenticate?

`Catch` this exception explicitly and do nothing inside the block, for example:

```
catch(CredentialUnavailableException ex)
{}
```

Comment: I'm developing on my local machine, not a VM, and I'm authenticated with Azure CLI.

Comment: Can you try adding these environment variables?

Comment: Adding the env vars on the local machine could help. But I solved this differently. I created two SecretClient beans for dev profile and one for stag/prod profile. On dev profile I use AzureCliCredential, because we are authenticating with azure CLI, and on stag/prog I used ManagedIdentityCredential because that is used on the cloud.

Comment: Ohh okay, does the second part of my answer helps you for catching exception?

Comment: It helped, but with the solution that I described above, the errors are gone, since I'm using an explicit method for authentications and not the default one.